# How to assign object literal to variable with private properties

Tags: typescript

Consider the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
  public prop1: string;
  private prop2: string;
}
```

How can I assign to an instance of this class using an object literal in TypeScript?

```
var x: MyClass = {
  prop1: "a",
  prop2: "b" // compiler complains that prop2 is public not private
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort of do it now using object spread:

```
var x: MyClass = {
  prop1: "a",
  ...{} as any
};
```

Comment: I have no clue why it works, but it works. :shrug:

Comment: 2 hours of trying various things, this worked wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add to your answer the reason this works, or what is actually happening here?

Answer (score 3):

Private properties are designed to disallow this kind of thing. The best thing to do is use a type assertion to `any`:

```
var x: MyClass = <any>{
  prop1: "a",
  prop2: "b"
};
```

Comment: any solution where i don't lose intellisense?